# Converting character timestamp to date-time stamp in R; H:M:S keeps getting removed

Tags: r, timestamp, lubridate, posixct

I am trying to convert a character date-time stamp to a normalised date-time stamp in R but running into the same issue with a number different solutions. Here is a sample:-

```
timesdf<-structure(list(DateTime = c("2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", 
                                     "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", 
                                     "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", 
                                     "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", 
                                     "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", 
                                     "2021-02-20 00:00:00")), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")


str(timesdf)
#'data.frame':  15 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ DateTime: chr  "2021-02-20 00:00:00" "2021-02-20 00:00:00" "2021-02-20 00:00:00" "2021-02-20 00:00:00" ...
```

Here is are some of the solutions that I have tried:-

```
#lubridate solution 1
timesdf$DateTime<-ymd_hms(timesdf$DateTime)
timesdf
head(timesdf)
#    DateTime
#1 2021-02-20
#2 2021-02-20
#3 2021-02-20
#4 2021-02-20
#5 2021-02-20
#6 2021-02-20


#lubridate solution 2
timesdf$DateTime<-ymd_hms(timesdf$DateTime,tz=Sys.timezone())
timesdf
head(timesdf)
#    DateTime
#1 2021-02-20
#2 2021-02-20
#3 2021-02-20
#4 2021-02-20
#5 2021-02-20
#6 2021-02-20



#POSIXct solution 1
timesdf$DateTime<-as.POSIXct(timesdf$DateTime, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS")
#Warning messages:
#1: In strptime(xx, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS'
#2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS'
#3: In strptime(x, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS'
#4: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...) :
#  unknown timezone '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS'
head(timesdf)
#    DateTime
#1 2021-02-20
#2 2021-02-20
#3 2021-02-20
#4 2021-02-20
#5 2021-02-20
#6 2021-02-20


#POSIXct solution 2
timesdf$DateTime<-as.POSIXct(timesdf$DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%0S")
#Warning messages:
#  1: In strptime(xx, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
#2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
#3: In strptime(x, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
#4: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...) :
#  unknown timezone '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
head(timesdf)
#    DateTime
#1 2021-02-20
#2 2021-02-20
#3 2021-02-20
#4 2021-02-20
#5 2021-02-20
#6 2021-02-20
```

As you can see, the H:M:S part of the timestamp is being removed, which is not what I want.
I usually use `lubridate` to normalise date-time stamps and if that (seldom) fails then I use the `as.POSIXct` function. But I have no idea why the H:M:S part is being removed.

This is likely a duplicate question but I haven't found anything obvious that was similar to my issue. Any pointers would be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you understand the difference between how an R object is stored internally and how it is printed? You seem to be concerned about the latter. Why?

Comment: As @Roland indicates, I think you are confusing the formated printed output from an object and its internal representation.  Try changing the time part of just one of the dates to something other than "00:00:00.00" and see what happens.  If that doesn't help, think about what happens when you print a vector/tibble column real numbers, round them to integers and print them again.

Comment: I do understand that there is a difference between how certain objects are stored and how it is printed, perhaps I did not convey my issue well.  But I am also experiencing other issues, such as a warning message ```All formats failed to parse. No formats found```, so even by trying to cut the problem in different ways, I am still not able to normalise my date-time stamps. I will amend my OP to explain further

Comment: Your datetime format is the standard default. You can simply do `as.POSIXct(timesdf$DateTime, tz = "UTC")` (adjust the time zone as needed). The default print method omits the time for midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem is just how the data are *printed*. To convince yourself, just try to add 1 to the variable created by `POSIXct`:

```r
timesdf<-structure(list(DateTime = c("2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", 
                                     "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", 
                                     "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", 
                                     "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", 
                                     "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", "2021-02-20 00:00:00", 
                                     "2021-02-20 00:00:00")), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

timesdf <- timesdf |> 
  mutate(times = as.POSIXct(DateTime))

head(timesdf)
#>              DateTime      times
#> 1 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20
#> 2 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20
#> 3 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20
#> 4 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20
#> 5 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20
#> 6 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20

timesdf |> 
  mutate(times = times + 1) |> 
  head()
#>              DateTime               times
#> 1 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20 00:00:01
#> 2 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20 00:00:01
#> 3 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20 00:00:01
#> 4 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20 00:00:01
#> 5 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20 00:00:01
#> 6 2021-02-20 00:00:00 2021-02-20 00:00:01
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The errors you get from your `POSIXct` command ("unknown time zone") is due to the fact that the second argument to the `POSIXct` function is `tz`, as you see from the code above you don't have to specify the format.